# Discord.py | Объявление об ошибке

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@Bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def unban(ctx, id: int):
    user = await Bot.fetch_user(id)
    await ctx.guild.unban(user)
    await ctx.send(user.name + " разбанен!")
```

**Задача кода:** 
При использовании команды нужно добавить `discord ID` пользователя для того чтобы бот разбанил пользователя.
• **Пример:** c:unban `ID пользователя` | c:unban 6125347980896752431 \

**Моя проблема:** 
Я хочу сделать условие того, что если в списке банов сервера не находится пользователь с определенным ID, то бот выведет сообщение о том что данный ID не был обнаружен.

Вот другой пример разбана с тем чего я хочу, но он выполнен по другому методу:

```
@Bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def unban(ctx, member):
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
    member_name, member_disc = member.split('#')
    for banned_entry in banned_users:
        user = banned_entry.user
        if(user.name, user.discriminator)==(member_name, member_disc):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            await ctx.send(member_name + " has been unbaned!")
            return
    await ctx.send(member + " не был обнаружен") # <- вот что мне нужно.
```

Данная команда работает по методу: с:unban `ник и дискриминатор` | c:unban Nick#9999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для команды `unban`, принимаем аргумент `member` как `int` - здесь будет `id`:

```
async def unban(ctx, member: int = None):
```

Затем получаем список забаненных пользователей и проверяем, есть ли там указанный `id`:

```
banlist = await ctx.guild.bans()

for m in banlist:
    if m.user.id == member:
        member = await Bot.fetch_user(member)
        await ctx.guild.unban(member)
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f'{member.name} разабнен!', colour = discord.Color.gold()))
        return
```

Если же условие в цикле не было выполнено, обрабатываем исключение, так как пользователя с указанным `id` в списке банов не нашлось:

```
await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f'{ctx.author.mention}, пользователь с указанным `ID` на данном сервере не забанен', colour = discord.Color.red()))
```

---

Для команды `ban` вы можете избежать всех этих проверок, просто указывая пользователя через упоминание. Для этого нужно оформить тип аргумента `member` как `discord.Member`

```
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
```

Теперь есть только 2 исключения - **пользователь не указан** и **указанный пользователь не найден**.

При первом, аргумент `member` примет значение `None`, соответственно, можем обработать это исключение через `if member == None:`

Второе исключение проще обработать через событие бота `on_command_error()`:

Если происходит ошибка, то обрабатываем именно исключение "*не найден участник сервера*" - `commands.errors.MemberNotFound`

```
@Bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.MemberNotFound):
        msg = await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f'{ctx.author.mention}, указанный пользователь не найден', colour = discord.Color.red()))
        await sleep(5)
        await msg.delete()
        try:
            await ctx.message.delete()
        except:
            pass
```

---

### Результат:

**`ban`**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**`unban`**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Полный код:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from asyncio import sleep

Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

@Bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def unban(ctx, member: int = None):
    if member == None:
        msg = await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f'{ctx.author.mention}, укажите `ID` пользователя для разбана', colour = discord.Color.red()))
        await sleep(5)
        await msg.delete()
        await ctx.message.delete()
        return

    banlist = await ctx.guild.bans()
    for m in banlist:
        if m.user.id == member:
            member = await Bot.fetch_user(member)
            await ctx.guild.unban(member)
            await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f'{member.name} разабнен!', colour = discord.Color.gold()))
            return

    msg = await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f'{ctx.author.mention}, пользователь с указанным `ID` на данном сервере не забанен', colour = discord.Color.red()))
    await sleep(5)
    await msg.delete()
    await ctx.message.delete()

@Bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member == None:
        msg = await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f'{ctx.author.mention}, укажите пользователя для бана', colour = discord.Color.red()))
        await sleep(5)
        await msg.delete()
        await ctx.message.delete()
        return

    await ctx.guild.ban(member)
    await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f'{member.mention} забанен!', colour = discord.Color.gold()))

@Bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.MemberNotFound):
        msg = await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f'{ctx.author.mention}, указанный пользователь не найден', colour = discord.Color.red()))
        await sleep(5)
        await msg.delete()
        await ctx.message.delete()

    else:
        print(error)

Bot.run('TOKEN')
```

**Не забудьте указать токен!**

Comment: Хорошо, идея достаточно не сложная и хороша. Но как поменять чтобы все шло через ID, так как когда участник находится в списке банов, ты никак не сможешь его упомянуть. Я попробовал поменять чтоб это работало через ID, но теперь ошибку не хочет выдавать.

Comment: Дополнил ответ, спасибо за уточнение